# Getting the database ID of the newly saved data and passing it to previous activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I am having a workflow as shown in the below picture.

[image]

1. Clicks the "New" entry button in `Home` activity
2. Enter the entry details in `NewEntry` activity
3. Click "Save" in `NewEntry` activity
4. Navigate back to `Home` activity

While I am navigating back to `Home` activity, I pass the new entry details from `NewEntry` activity to `Home` activity using `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` function.

I am able to receive the data too, except the database `ID` of the newly saved data. I save the new entry data to the database using an `AsyncTask.execute()` in another thread. Only once the entry is saved in the database, I will get the `ID` of the entry in a callback function.

But, once I press the back button and save entry `AsyncTask` gets called and it navigates back to `Home` activity. Since the `ID` is not set for the new entry until the `AsyncTask` execution completes, I get no value for `ID` in my `Home` activity in the received intent.

**I want to get the database value of `ID` and pass it to `Home` activity for other purposes. This way I don't have to refresh the whole list in `Home` activity to show the new entry**

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: just a suggestion, generate local UUID and use it as ID, make it in way so you do not get collisions.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks. I did think of generating a unique ID like that. But, I just wanted to see whether there are more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: No problem btw are you going on ITU

Answer (score 2):

You can send a broadcast from your AsyncTask or use an event bus like GreenRobot or Otto.

But a better solution would be to have a loader in your main activity, so whenever something changes in the database, it reloads the data, so you do not need to pass the data back in onResult and then pass the ID at a later time. Using a loader and content provider (assuming you're using a SQLite database) would do everything for you for free.

Comment: I will read more about using loaders. But, I currently follow a MVP pattern in the application.